# How can I give this row a class="right"

Tags: java, jsf

I have  a datatable like that:

```
  <h:dataTable  styleClass="pretty"   value="#{ftController.ftDataModel}" var="item">
                    <h:column headerClass="left">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputLink   value="index.jsf"><h:outputText value="#{item.ftType}"/></h:outputLink><br />
                        <h:outputText class="red" id="amount"   value="#{item.amount}"></h:outputText> <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText  style="font-size:12px" class="gray" value="TL" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column headerClass="right" >
                        <f:facet  name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Date"/>
                        </f:facet> 
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.date}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

I want to gives this `<h:outputText value="#{item.date}" />` class="right" how can I use class attribute on **only** this row?

Comment: i just want to give class attribute to <h:outputText value="#{item.date}" /> this

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but I suspect your question might be based off of a mistaken assumption about datatables. Take this datatable for example:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{foo.selectedWidgets}" var="widget">
    <h:column>
         #{widget.name}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The contents of an `<h:column>` tag (with the exception of a header facet) -- in my example,  `#{widget.name}` -- is *not* a row. Rather, it is the template for ALL the `<td>` tags that are going to be generated for the given column. For *every* widget that this dataTable loops over, it will print the widget's name attribute -- this is what I mean by a "template". So anything that you do to an h:column will affect *the entire column*, not any particular row.

My solution to this is non-JSF. Use a CSS sheet, and use the `first-child` or `nth-child` selectors to pick out the row you want to style.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping that outputtext in h:panelGroup
This will generate a span tag and using styleclass you can assign the required css class